# JSON - compare a field across many records and resolve type discrepancies

Tags: json, apache-drill, bigdata

In one record (JSON object), we have

```
      {
        "name": "ID",
        "value": "4260567,4260556"
      }
```

In another record, we have

```
      {
        "name": "ID",
        "value": {}
      }
```

My issue is that this dataset cannot be queried in Apache Drill because of the different types being used for one field - strings in one case and objects in others. I also can't replace {} with "" across the board, because there are other fields that are actually supposed to be objects that this would cause the same issue with.

My idea is to write some code to load in a batch of data, and go through field by field crosschecking records and correct these type mismatches. For example, if it sees that most of the entries in this ID field are strings and only some are empty objects, it'll convert those to empty strings. If it sees that some values are arrays/lists and other values in the same field are single objects, it'll convert those single objects to arrays/lists. Things like that.

However that's a pretty big undertaking for just one dataset. Are there any other ways for me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an [experimental UNION setting](https://drill.apache.org/docs/json-data-model/#experimental-feature:-heterogeneous-types) you can try, `exec.enable_union_type`:

```
ALTER SESSION SET `exec.enable_union_type` = true;
```

**Details**

I'm using Drill 1.6.  I used the following test data:

```
[
    {
        "name": "foo",
        "value": "4260567,4260556"
    },
    {
        "name": "bar",
        "value": {}
    },
    {
        "name": "baz",
        "value": ["one", "two", "three"]
    }
]
```

And ran a simple query

```
SELECT * FROM dfs.`/tmp/drill-sample.json`;
```

Which results in this error

> Error: DATA_READ ERROR: Error parsing JSON - You tried to start when you are using a ValueWriter of type NullableVarCharWriterImpl.
>
> File  /tmp/drill-sample.json
>   Record  2
>   Fragment 0:0

**Fix**

```
ALTER SESSION SET `exec.enable_union_type` = true;
```

Now the JSON parsing works

```
0: jdbc:drill:zk=local> SELECT * FROM dfs.`/tmp/drill-sample.json`;
+-------+------------------------+
| name  |         value          |
+-------+------------------------+
| foo   | 4260567,4260556        |
| bar   | {}                     |
| baz   | ["one","two","three"]  |
+-------+------------------------+
3 rows selected (1.106 seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you! Does this also work when you have some members of a field in an array and others as a single element?

Comment: Yes, it does work with array values.  I updated the answer to include an array.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'm actually encountering a new error now, but I can't find documentation for this or a similar error anywhere. 'Error: DATA_READ ERROR: index: 0, length: 65536 (expected: range(0, 32768))' and the error does point to a specific record and field in the dataset. I was thinking to post another question but I figured I'd ask you first